# Unable to point to a Amazon s3 url using Amazon route 53

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I am trying to create a record set in route 53 that will point to one of my static file on s3.

Ex: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/terms-conditions/termsconditions.html

I have created a CNAME record in route 53

"termsconditions.mydomain.com"

and in the value I have given the s3 url.

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/terms-conditions/termsconditions.html

The record was saved without any errors. But now when I go to 
termsconditions.mydomain.com I don't get any response.

Any idea why this is not working?

I have configured other record sets and pointed to EC2 instances and loadbalancers and they are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Amazon Route 53 to point to an Amazon S3 bucket:

- The S3 bucket must be named the same as your domain, eg `termsconditions.mydomain.com`
- Configure the bucket for **static website hosting**
- Create a Route 53 record set to alias the domain name to the S3 bucket

Note that the record set can only point to the "domain portion" of the URL, not the whole URL. So, you'll need to use a bucket that is named `termsconditions.mydomain.com` and then access the page via the **complete URL** of `termsconditions.mydomain.com/termsconditions.html`.

If you want to just use the domain portion of a URL (eg `termsconditions.mydomain.com`) to direct to a specific page, define that page as the "Index" document in the Static Website Hosting configuration page.

See: [Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)